# Different Chanukah Blessing for Converts?

Tags: sources-mekorot, blessing, conversion-to-judaism, chanuka

In 139:12, Kitzur writes that when a convert lights Chanukah candles, he should say "She-asah nissim l'Yisrael" instead of "She-asah nissim lavoteinu". What is his basis for this ruling? Isn't a halachically valid convert treated the same as a born Jew?

I can find several reasons to disagree with Kitzur, for example that "avoteinu" means "our fathers", i.e. the fathers of the Jewish nation, not "my fathers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rambam raises the possibility of a convert reciting such a variant blessing in a responsum to R. Ovadya the proselyte (ed. Blau #293) that references the Jews, rather than "our forefathers" and writes that he may recite such a variant. However, he emphasizes that he is equally entitled to recite the traditional formula that references our forefathers, (and he seems to prefer this latter option):

> **אבל שהוצאתנו ממצרים או שעשית נסים לאבותינו אם רצית לשנות ולומר שהוצאת את ישראל ממצרים ושעשית נסים עם ישראל אמור. ואם לא שנית אין בכך הפסד כלום** מאחר שנכנסת תחת כנפי השכינה ונלוית אליו **אין כאן הפרש בינינו ובינך. וכל הנסים שנעשו כאלו לנו ולך נעשו**. הרי הוא אומר בישעיה ואל יאמר בן הנכר הנלוה אל ה' לאמר הבדל הבדילני /יבדילני/ ה' מעל עמו וגו', אין שום הפרש כלל בינינו ובינך לכל דבר. ודאי יש לך לברך אשר בחר בנו ואשר נתן לנו ואשר הנחילנו ואשר הבדילנו. ש**כבר בחר בך הבורא יתעלה והבדילך מן האומות ונתן לך התורה שהתורה לנו ולגרים שנ' הקהל חוקה אחת לכם ולגר הגר חוקת עולם לדורותיכם ככם כגר יהיה לפני י"י**. תורה אחת ומשפט אחד יהיה לכם ולגר הגר אתכם. ודע כי אבותינו שיצאו ממצרים רובם עובדי ע"ז היו במצרים נתערבו בגוים ולמדו מעשיהם עד ששלח הקדוש ברוך הוא משה רבינו ע"ה רבן של כל הנביאים והבדילנו מן העמים והכניסנו תחת כנפי השכינה לנו ולכל הגרים ושם לכולנו חוקה אחת. ואל יהא יחוסך קל בעיניך אם אנו מתיחסים לאברהם יצחק ויעקב אתה מתיחס למי שאמר והיה העולם. וכך מפורש בישעיה זה יאמר לי"י אני וזה יקרא בשם יעקב וגו'. **וכל מה שאמרנו לך בענין הברכות שלא תשנה** כבר ראיה לזה ממסכת בכוריםו תמן תנינן הגר מביא ואינו קורא שאינו יכול לומר אשר נשבע י"י לאבותינו לתת לנו. וכשהוא מתפלל בינו לבין עצמו אומר אלהינו ואלהי אבות ישראל. וכשהוא מתפלל בבית הכנסת אומר אלהינו ואלהי אבותינוז זהו סתם משנה. והיא לר' מאיר ואינה הלכהח אלא כמו שנתפרש בירושלמי תמן אמרינן תני בשם ר' יהודה גר עצמו מביא וקורא מאי טעמיה כי אב המון גוים נתתיך לשעבר היית אבי לאברהם מיכאן ואילך אב לכל הבריות. ר' יהושע בן לוי אמר הלכה כר' יהודה. אתא עובדא קמיה דר' אבהו והורי כר' יהודה. הנה נתברר לך שיש לך לומר אשר נשבע י"י לאבותינו לתת לנו. ושאברהם אב לך ולנו ולכל הצדיקים ללכת בדרכיו והוא הדין לשאר הברכות והתפלות שלא תשנה כלום. וכתב משה ב"ר מימון זצ"ליב

This responsum is referenced by the Elya Rabba (676:2) who seems to rule accordingly.

However, R. Saadiah Halevi Mirkado (18th-19th cent.) notes in his Neve Tzedek (Hilkhot Megillah v'Hannukah 3:4) that Rambam rules in Hilkhot Ma'aser Sheni (11:17) that converts cannot recite the declaration on *ma'aser*, since it contains the words "the land that you gave to our forefathers". R. Mirkado, therefore seems to prefer that a convert similarly recite the variant formula for Hannuka candles.

It should be noted that even the Kitsur Shulhan Arukh (139:12) who prefers the variant formula concedes that if the traditional formula is recited, that is sufficient.

> גר אומר שעשה נסים לישראל ואם אמר לאבותינו יצא

Comment: The Kitsur doesn't state his source. R. Mirkado shows a possible precedent from Rambam himself. Furthermore, R. Mirkado precedes the Kitsur, and although the Kitsur probably didn't see his work, provides an earlier source for his ruling.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question, the Kitsur Shulchan Aruch here addresses a point which is not apparent in Shulchan Aruch in hilchot Chanuka.

See Mishna Bikkurim 1, 4.  This Mishna says that a convert cannot read mikra  Bikkurim because he cannot say "the country which the Lord swore to our fathers to give us"  (Deuteronomy 26, 3). When a convert prays alone,  he says "the G-d of the fathers of Israel" . When he prays in synagogue for the congregation,  he says "the G-d of your fathers". Commentators on the Mishna report that in Talmud of Jerusalem the conclusion follows a Berayta that says that  converts say "the G-d of our fathers" and read mikra Bikkurim because the land of Israel was given to Avraham who is the father of converts. Rambam rules as this Jerusalem's Talmud.

But for Vidui maasser it is different. Convert cannot say "and the land which you have given us,  as you swore to our fathers,  a land that flows with milk and honey.“ (Deuteronomy 26, 15).

Some Rishonim and poskim acharonim see no difference and concluded that convert bless.  But if we want to understand the Rambam we need to understand why in mikra Bikkurim he rules that convert says the verse mentioning the land and the fathers and in Maasser sheni,  he cannot.

[Rabbi Meir Itschaki on Rambam Maasser sheni 11, 17](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=7553&rid=7179) writes in name of Rashi on Chumash explains the difference. Rashi points that for the verse of Maasser Sheni the Mishna needs to quote the verse up to "milk and honey". The REM on Rashi explains that the mention of "flows milk..."  was a swore said to the generation which get out of Egypt. Not to Avraham. In the same way regarding Al Hanisim. The commentators on Rambam report [Shut Shaar Efraim 14](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1405&st=&pgnum=26&hilite=)  with two answers to the contradiction in Rambam (First teruts: for Vidui Maassrot the Vidui contains a prayer, and for a prayer one needs to feel wholly each word. As in some periods people didn't say Gadol Gibbor and Nora in prayer. But for  mikra Bikkurim the recitation is a praise and no problem. BTW the blessing of Sheassa Nissim is also  a prise as mikra Bikkurim and we can understand the  Shut  Harambam quoted by @mevaqesh in which Rambam says that the convert can say laavotenu. Second teruts by the  son of the author: in Bikkurim the point is on the promise to give the land to the whole Israeli nation but in Maassrot) the point is on the personal ownership)   and the [Shut Shay Lamora 54](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9204&st=&pgnum=123) (the teruts he retained: maasser the accent is on the actual giving of the land. In Bikkurim the accent is on the promise. potentially all descendants of Avraham were able to  receive a part of the land.  But  those who reached Israeli people after the division of the land or who were excluded as the tribe of Levi did not get any part. They are linked to the promise but not to the division. No problem for mikra Bikkurim. Indeed for Vidui Maasser,  we search an actual part.  E. g.  for Leviim Rabbi Yose says that they make Vidui because their ownership of Are Miklat. Second teruts, the gift pointed in Bikkurim is the fruits of the land,  not the land. But in Maasrot the land itself is pointed)  . I hope to find time to explain their  Teruts.  A master piece of the Suggia is the Tosfot Baba Batra 81a with the opinion of Rabenu Tam regarding Zimun for a convert.

(The Peri Megadim Eshel Avraham OC 186, sk 1 addresses the question of convert regarding second blessing of Birkat Hamazon.)

Even if we follow the Rambam,  regarding the miracles of Chanukka,  they were not made at the time of Avraham. So,  possibly, in Al Hanisim we expect that a convert says "the miracles you made for fathers of Israel",  not  "our fathers". But this pilpul is not inescapable.

Conclusion: The KSA understanding of Sheassa Nissim disagree with the two  terutsim of the Shaar Efraim and the tertsim of the  Shay Lamora in Rambam,  but is congruent to the Teruts of Rabbi Meir Itschaki in Rambam.